# Getting error while trying to "ChooseData Source" for grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

2 days ago, I am trying to uninstalled Oracle Database from my PC. 
then i uninstalled Oracle completely and then re-installed it.

Is it problem for this error?

I attached Error Image.
Please reply me as soon as possible.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

At this point I we cannot know if there is a problem with the database itself yet. Because the system couldn't find the .dll file which is responsible to reach Oracle's libraries.

- Check if you re-added the dll file mentioned to your project as a reference.
- Check if the file is actually there.
- Check if the version of the file is correct.